# R array - subsetting with dummy singleton dimension

Tags: r

I've been writing a number of functions on arrays in R that are of an image-processing type.

What this means is that the functions operate on:

- a n by m by 3 array (colour), or
- an n by m (by 1) array (greyscale).

The thing is, greyscale images are 2-dimensional: `dim(ary)` is `c(n,m)`.
By contrast, colour images are 3-dimensional: `dim(ary)` is `c(n,m,3)`.

At the moment my functions all have something like (following example is contrived but demonstrates my problem):

```
f <- function(img)
{
    if ( length(dim(img)) == 2 )
        return( img[1:10,] )
    else
        return( img[1:10,,] )   # Note the extra comma to select all 3D slices?
}
```

That is, I always have to include a check to say "if it's a two-dimensional array then don't put in the extra comma that indicates "everything in the third dimension"".

Is there some way I can get around this? Since a 2-dimensional array is really a 3-dimensional array with `dim(ary) = c(n,m,1)`, it'd be great to use the same subsetting syntax for both.

**Is there some way I can tell R  "if I add in one too many commas in the indexing, you should assume that is a singleton dimension" ?**

(I suppose I could do the reshaping myself via `dim(img) <- c(dim(img),1)`, but that still requires me to check that `length(dim(img))==2` and I'd like know if there's away to avoid this check at the start of every function.

Comment: FWIW, there is a lot of support in R for greyscale and RGB images, see ?as.raster in grDevices, also the pixmap, sp, rgdal, raster, and other packages

Comment: I know, I'm writing image processing functions that make use of these packages (particularly grid/grDevices/raster/pixmap).

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to put a class on your objects -- either grey or colour -- and then the subscripting function for 'grey' objects can just ignore the last dimension.  The `[` method for the colour objects need not even exist.